Were the common people in Germany ("good germans") morally co-responsible of the war crimes of their government?
I'm relatively new to philosophy and just dipping my toes into moral philosophy (ethics). I'd be interested in finding answers to this question:
Were the common people in WW2 Germany morally co-responsible of the war crimes of their government?
I have developed a view on this: Absolutely they were co-responsible because they enabled the Nazi-government, most were active part of system and supplied moral and material support for German military. Furthermore, I'd suspect that the majority of the adult Germans (including the women) knew about the human rights crimes (segregation, concentration- & destruction camps), which were too numerous to be kept secret.
I also developed counter-views: the "good Germans" were manipulated, mentally castrated, just "following orders", "trying to survive" or "couldn't change the situation" - to an extent where they simply didn't participate in evil-doing in their own opinion. In other words that they created a parallel moral system where they were actually doing good. However, I don't like these relativistic arguments since I believe that objective morality exists, or that certain things are always bad regardless of a situation.
So I'd would like compare my view with what real philosophers have written. Please feel free to comment here or recommend reading material. I haven't found any books or articles on this specific topic yet, so I'd be glad to get some references.
Thanks,
RR
(PS: There are plenty of books and films that at least partly describe WW2 from common people's point-of-view but I haven't found anything that considers the moral responsibility of the common people.)
(PS2: Looks like the question was closed as off-topic. It's quite difficult for me to understand what questions could be more about philosophy than moral ones. I accept my fate and look for answers elsewhere.)

You have to consider Hannah Arendt's works.

Real-world situations are complex and nuanced - people don't necessarily agree on what the "common people" knew at which points, and how easily they could influence that, so one first has to establish those things, and then one can discuss the morality of it all. That arguably makes the question too broad, and involve History which goes beyond philosophy. Presenting a clean hypothetical would probably lead to more useful answers about morality (or ask on the History site if you want to focus on that side of the issue).

@Servaes "It is widely known that the vast majority of Germans had no idea of the atrocities occuring in what they believed to be 'just' labor camps" - One might argue that standing by while your elected government is rounding people up and and shipping them to camps for the purposes of slave labor is also immoral.

"Absolutely they were co-responsible because they enabled the Nazi-government, most were active part of system and supplied moral and material support for German military." But then, are citizens of a modern democracy whose government is killing and bombing thousands of civilian "collective responsible" for what the government is doing? Any reference to current events IS intentional...

WW2 is old stuff, and a bit too safe. You could take a more contemporaneous case, like the 2003 Iraq war. Are all American citizens morally responsible for the hundreds of thousands of death that resulted from it? Or only those who supported it? Or only the actual perpetrators, ie the soldiers, the White House (W, Cheney and co), the members of congress who voted for it (including Biden), and the journalists who conveyed lies from the US administration (including the NYT)? Unfortunately there was no Nurember trial for that case...

Speaking about “the common people” is always a problematic task.

It seems that there is a whole spectrum of cases concerning the own
co-responsibility for the war-crimes of one’s government.
The spectrum ranges from the members of the resistance via those who
wink at the crimes, and the nominal members to the active members in
the nazi organization, the members of the government, and the
soldiers of the  military forces.
At the ends of the spectrum: The members of the resistance were not
responsible, while the active members in the nazi organization, the
members of the governments and the soldiers were reponsible.

What about those who winked at the crimes and the nominal members?
This brings up the question: Are those persons, in particular those
who knew about the concentration camps and about the program of the
holocaust, obliged to protest? And to risk their own life and the life
of their family members when protesting?

I have no general answer. I can only vote for a
differenciated judgement.
The writings of Hannah Arendt are often
named in this context. The post also relates to the theme of moral
courage in a dictatorial regime.



"the soldiers were reponsible" - including naval personnel who rescued survivors of a sunken British ship (while said survivors were being bombed by the Americans), including many civilians, because the British were irresponsible enough to sell tickets to civilians for a naval vessel because they thought no Germans could reach so far south? These Germans were guilty of war crimes merely for being enlisted in the navy? And the Americans who bombed rescued British civilians just to sink a German vessel, were not?

@vsz The quoted link reports that the German submarines U-156 and U-506 sank several ships during the German submarine warfare. It was U-156 which first sank Laconia and afterwards rescued several Laconia survivors.

I'm the author of this question. I did enjoy this answer tremendously, many thanks. I thought this was a simple matter but looks like there are more facets to this as I anticipated. Philosophy is hard.
